# Why is my /etc/hosts file not queried when nslookup tries to resolve an address?

Tags: dns, hosts

I have a couple of local domains resolved to `127.0.0.1` in my `/etc/hosts` file. And it was all alright for a period of time but now when I run:

```
nslookup test.local
```

It results in:

```
Server:     192.168.1.3
Address:    192.168.1.3#53

** server can't find test.local: NXDOMAIN
```

The `192.168.1.3` is our network DNS and it's not supposed to know my local domain `test.local`. After a couple of searches I found that `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file holds information on the priority of the DNS sources to query by. But there was no problem there! Here's mine:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

So does anyone know why my `hosts` file is not included in DNS look-up?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`nslookup` only does *proper* DNS resolution, which is significantly different from the [Name Service Switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch) subsystem that your other applications use; that is to say `nslookup` ignores `/etc/hosts` and mDNS.

To test local resolutions like that, use something that uses NSS. `ping <hostname>` for example. Here's a simple demo based on an `/etc/hosts` entry on my network.

```
$ nslookup bert
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find bert: NXDOMAIN

$ ping bert
PING bert (10.10.0.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from bert (10.10.0.4): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.352 ms
64 bytes from bert (10.10.0.4): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.407 ms
```

Note that there are DNS servers and proxies that can factor in an `/etc/hosts` file. In these cases, `nslookup` might return a result from a local source.

Comment: Instead of `ping` one should be using `getent ahosts` because that does not require all the extra stuff that `ping` has.

Comment: ^--- this should be its own answer. Been using `getent` for years for user & group info - had no idea it could handle DNS.

Comment: Why do you say that nslookup ignores /etc/hosts?  When I run nslookup on an IP address, it gives me entries that exist only in my /etc/hosts.  In fact, I'm trying to figure out how to get nslookup to ignore /etc/hosts.

Answer (score 2):

Another common thing I see is where somebody (usually me) reverses the IP address with the hostname in `/etc/hosts` - for example:

```
mysite.com    10.2.3.4
```

At first glance, it looks normal... Here is my solution about 50% of the time:

```
10.2.3.4    mysite.com
```

Comment: guilty of it this time...#sigh

Comment: Usually the hosts files comes with predefined 127.0.0.1 localhost entry. Doing it wrong is so much wrong :-)

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you want the name resolution from `/etc/hosts` file for the specific host (mysite.com).

Another common problem that can cause this behavior is that you may have many entries on the `/etc/hosts` file for the same IP, example:

```
1.1.1.1 host1.domain1.com
1.1.1.1 host2.domain2.com
```

In some implementations, this can cause the name resolution to get handed to DNS. A quick fix, group everything in 1 row

```
1.1.1.1 host1.domain1.com host2.domain2.com
```